# How to check for piped data in perl script

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell, stdin

I am currently using these two if statements to decide if data is being piped in or is from a file:

```
pod2usage("$NAME: Requires at least one argument FILE.\n") if ((-t STDIN) && (@ARGV == 0));
pod2usage("$NAME: zero if input is from STDIN.\n") if (!(-t STDIN) && (@ARGV != 0));
```

This works fine when the perl script is run interactively from the shell. For example these work as expected:

```
$ perl_script <flags> filename
$ cat | perl_script <flags>
```

However, when the perl script is called from a bash script or something like org-mode in emacs the script thinks it is having data being piped in and throws the pod2usage error when files are given as arguments. Here is an example that causes this behavior:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
perl_script <flags> $line  >> output_file
done < file_names.txt
```

I am guessing that this is happening because `-t STDIN` is returning false because it is being run non-interactively so it is not attached to a terminal. Is there a way to make sure that I get the proper behavior if the script is being ran interactively or if being called from a shell script?

Comment: `-t` returns true even if your script isn't on the read end of a pipe: `perl -wE 'say "tty" if -t'`. The only way to know if something is being passed to STDIN is to try to read from it.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Can you give an example?

Comment: i.e. `while (<>) { ... }`. This will block and wait for input if you don't pass a filename as an argument or pipe data to STDIN, which is exactly what *nix utilities (e.g. `cat`, `awk`, `wc`) typically do. In other words, I would remove the check you have now; you can't reliably test whether the user is inputting something to STDIN (they could be in the process of typing it when you do your check), so don't try. Instead, do what existing programs do: allow the user to pass a filename as an argument, enter data via a pipe, or manually via the prompt.

Comment: I think, if `@ARGV != 0`, you should simply ignore the `stdin`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks. Updated my scripts to work like other *nix coreutils and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
TTY=`tty`
while read line
do
perl_script <flags> $line  < $TTY >> output_file
done < file_names.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer script is supplying file_names.txt on STDIN to the loop, which gets picked up by any child process in the loop.  Your logic (in-so-far as your inner script is concerned) is correct.  However, it's getting input in 2 ways: a file name on the command line and as a redirect of the file_names.txt file on STDIN supplied to the loop that is not connected to a tty.  That's one of my main complaints about looping in bash.  The STDIN redirect is kind of a loose canon and gets picked up unwittingly by the loop contents.  That's why I like tcsh's foreach:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
foreach line ( `cat file_names.txt` )
  perl_script <flags> $line  >> output_file
end
```

You may be able to do something like this in bash too, but I'm not certain whether your inner script would pick up the parent script's handle on STDIN (because I'm fairly new to bash and have been using tcsh for decades).  You can try it though and see if this works:

```
for line in `cat file_names.txt`; do perl_script <flags> $line  >> output_file; done
```